# Grub prompt never appears while installing Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 15R (N5110) with 3 partitions

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 11.10, dell, windows-7

The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15R (Queen).  It comes with Windows 7, and I want to install Ubuntu 11.10 on a different partition

The system has 3 primary partitions already:

1. a 100MB partition in FAT with 33MB used - located at the beginning of the drive
2. a Dell back-up partition - 15GB
3. the system partition

I did the proper defrag, etc. on Windows and then installed the system using the partition manager option.

Here comes the first problem, it asks me where should I install GRUB.  I have tried the 3 existing partitions (putting aside the ones I've created for the Linux install), but none of them worked. Windows 7 keeps on booting without the GRUB prompt ever appearing.

I've also tried to put GRUB on the newly created Ubuntu partitions, but nothing happened either. I know that the system is installed since the options of Ubuntu Live CD include new options such as to install over the already existing Ubuntu system, but I can't get GRUB to work.

The system has the following features:

- 6GB RAM
- 650GB HDD
- Intel Core i7 Processor
- 1GB Nvidia M525 Graphics

It's the 15R "Queen" setup.

Answer (score 1):

Grub needs to go to the MBR, in other words, `/dev/sda`, which is also the default choice. You could also install grub on the Ubuntu partition, and then use EasyBCD to make the Windows bootloader boot Ubuntu. Don't try installing Grub anywhere else, fist, it won't work, second, you might overwrite important files.

Link to EasyBCD: http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1