# 12.04 CD won't boot on my new Dell Inspiron 15R

Tags: installation, boot

My new UEFI Windows 8 Dell 15R will not boot from a live CD. It spins the optical drive like it's going to boot up, then hangs for a minute and says it can't find any bootable media.

Are there changes I should make in "bios"? UEFI is enabled, secure boot is on.

I do not want a dual boot system. I want WIndows 8 to be gone.

Comment: Three possible duplicates marked as such in my answer, last one talks about 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting another PC with the same CD/DVD, or perhaps try a CD/DVD from a magazine just to see if that works.

I believe you can turn secure boot off in the BIOS, though I have not seen that for real.

I assume the 15R can see the CD content if you just boot under Windows 8?

You could always try bootable USB if any/all of the above proves problematic (though if it is UEFI secure boot then you will have the same problem I think).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I put an old Linux Format DVD in the tray and rebooted. It's 12.04 32-bit. It booted fine. Now I'm at a loss. Why would a 32-bit version load and the 64-bit version fail? My system is 64-bit.

Comment: I think something was wrong with my ISO. I burned another DVD and it booted just fine. That you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

There are several things that could be happening here.

1. The ISO you downloaded and then burned to the disk somehow got corrupted. Try MD5ing or SHA1ing it and seeing if the MD5sum/SHA1sum matches the official sum
2. UEFI/Secure Boot is messing with the disk. Try this possible duplicate questions [Live CD won't start with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210220/live-cd-wont-start-with-uefi) - [I can't install Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15R at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182179/i-cant-install-ubuntu-on-my-dell-inspiron-15r-at-all?rq=1) - [I cant install ubuntu properly on my dell inspiron 15R (N5110)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95176/i-cant-install-ubuntu-properly-on-my-dell-inspiron-15r-n5110?rq=1)

Comment: It appears that's exactly what it was. I burned another copy of 12.04 and it booted just fine. Thank you.

Comment: @user189485: No problem, glad to have helped you solve your problem. Also, if an answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as answer and (if you so wish) up-vote it.